# Create a new column based on different dates for same disease for same individual

Tags: r, dplyr

| ID | conception | date_Dx | Dx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2005-11-14 | 2008-10-01 | xx |
| 1 | 2005-11-14 | 2008-04-08 | yy |
| 1 | 2005-11-14 | 2008-10-05 | xx |
| 1 | 2005-11-14 | 2008-04-08 | zz |

I am trying to create a new column (copy_Dx) whereby Dx is copied if someone has the same Dx on different date_Dx or else the value copied is 0. Basically, I am trying to define copy_Dx this way: More than one date with the same code (Dx) indicating particular disease.

I tried something like this:

```
df1 <- df%>%
group_by(ID, conception, Dx)%>%
  mutate(copy_Dx = if_else(n_distinct(date)>1, Dx,"0"))%>%
  ungroup()
```

But I get the following error :
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `true` must have size 1, not size 2.

I replaced if_else with ifelse, and that works, but I am wondering if there is a way to make it work with if_else.

Comment: since `n_distinct` always return length-1, I suggest something like `mutate(copy_dx = if (n_distinct(date) > 1) Dx else "0")`. If that doesn't work, please provide the expected output (literal frame please). Thanks!

Comment: For your comment "make it work with if_else", it's not the right tool for the job: your conditional is going to be length 1 _always_, which does not meet the "vectorized" notion of using `ifelse` or `if_else`. The literal adaptation for what you want is `if_else(rep(n_distinct(date) > 1, n()), Dx, "0")`, which is basically just `if (...)` as in my comment and answer. Don't try to shoe-horn `if_else` in where it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if` instead of `if_else`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(ID, conception, Dx) %>%
  mutate(copy_Dx = if (n_distinct(date_Dx) > 1) Dx else "0") %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#      ID conception date_Dx    Dx    copy_Dx
#   <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <chr>  
# 1     1 2005-11-14 2008-10-01 xx    xx     
# 2     1 2005-11-14 2008-04-08 yy    0      
# 3     1 2005-11-14 2008-10-05 xx    xx     
# 4     1 2005-11-14 2008-04-08 zz    0
```

Comment: Thank you @r2evans ! this answers my question. I appreciate the comments, it makes the explanation clear as to why if_else does not work. I I forgot that the conditional is going to be length 1 always, which does not meet the "vectorized" notion.